# Override/Disable iOS Smart Punctuation in TextInput

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-textinput

React Native 0.59.9 with device running iOS 11, and Smart Punctuation enabled. This iOS feature automatically converts entered text into more visually-pleasing notations.

Examples:

- double hyphen `--` gets autoconverted to an emdash `—` (unicode 8212)
- quotation mark `"` gets autoconverted to a curly quote `“`(unicode 8220)

etc.

Disabling Smart Punctuation (via Settings > General > Keyboard) is unfortunately not an option.

I render a basic `TextInput` component almost exactly as per the [RN docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html), with the only exception that I'm using my own `onChangeText` handler function to see the  effect on the entered text:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';


function handleTextChange(value) {
  // check value here after entering a '-' in the rendered TextInput.
  // when initial value is set to '', received value is ascii 45
  // when initial value is set to '-', received value is unicode 8212
}

export default function UselessTextInput() {
  const [value, onChangeText] = React.useState('-'); // change this to '' to see the difference

  return (
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={(text) => handleTextChange(text)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

Setting `autoCorrect={false}` and/or `autoCompleteType='off'` on the `<TextInput>` have no effect on the entered text.

**Question**
Is there a way to override this auto-correct behaviour so as to not change the user's inputted data?

I see that someone asked Facebook RN this question via a [Github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/20023), but got no response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, this is an issue with the TextInput's iOS implementation, but I can provide a workaround for you. The trick is to check the TextInput's value for special characters and then replace those characters appropriately. See example below, where I replace every "—" with "--".

**Code**

```
const UselessTextInput = () => {
  const [value, setText] = React.useState('-'); // change this to '' to see the difference

  function handleTextChange (value) {
    var val = value;
    // check if value contains special characters 
    if (value.includes("—")){
      //replace values appropriately
      val = value.replace("—", "--");
    }
    //set new text 
    setText(val);
  }
  return (
    <TextInput
      style={{ height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1 }}
      onChangeText={(text) => handleTextChange(text)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
}
```

**Working Example**:

https://snack.expo.io/rJkj95ePB

Comment: Works. Something to note here (for others) is that Smart Punctuation also converts `---` to an emdash. So replacing emdashes with `--` effectively prevents `---` from being entered. `---` would be 'corrected' to an emdash, and then fixed to `--` via the logic in your solution. Typing a third dash would be effectively impossible.

Answer (score 14):

it's not always an option but, adding:

```
keyboardType={'ascii-capable'}
```

to the TextInput fixed it for me

Comment: That worked for my use case. Thanks! If you can't force this keyboard, then you are left with replace option in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58004675/471574

Comment: Thank you so much! I freaking love you. I have been trying to find a fix for this for like 5 days. :'(

Comment: This is the correct answer. Simple and elegant...

Comment: This worked for me as. Thank you!