# Disable Smart Punctuation on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

iOS 11 has introduced Smart Punctuation, how can I explicitly disable it? This is causing problems for a Server which does not know how to handle these characters.

There are work arounds with writing regex to replace these special characters, however, I am wondering if it's possible to disable it globally or via a prop into the `TextInput` component.

Comment: I've already answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983965/override-disable-ios-smart-punctuation-in-textinput/58004675#58004675

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Override/Disable iOS Smart Punctuation in TextInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57983965/override-disable-ios-smart-punctuation-in-textinput)

Comment: @Tim the solution proposed is what I've mentioned in the second paragraph. Your solution does a replace, but this doesn't replace every smart punctuation char, there are double and single quotes too. What if Apple introduced more? This doesn't seem like a scalable solution.

Comment: Currently, there is no scalable solution. You can still adapt my solution to your needs.